# How to print Extended ascii character in perl command

Tags: perl, unix, datastage

How can I print an extended ascii character in a perl command?

I tried with below:

1.

```
-i.bak -pe "use open qw(:std :utf8);s/[^[:*ascii*:]]//g;"  #PS_BULK_GP.LOCAL_WORKING_FOLDER##TARGET_TABLE#.ftm
```

2.

```
-i.bak -pe "use open qw(:std :utf8);s/[^[:*print*:]]//g;"  #PS_BULK_GP.LOCAL_WORKING_FOLDER##TARGET_TABLE#.ftm
```

Comment: See [`perlrecharclass`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html). The POSIX character classes have the form `[:class:]`

Comment: I'm unclear what you mean. You ask how to *print* extended ASCII, but your code tries to *remove* non-ASCII (and non-printable) characters from a file.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a UTF-8 terminal,

```
perl -e'use open qw(:std :encoding(UTF-8)); CORE::say "\xE9\x{2661}";'

perl -CSDA -e'CORE::say "\xE9\x{2661}";'

perl -CSDA -Mutf8 -e'CORE::say "é♡";'
```

---

Tip: "Extended ascii character" is a poor way of saying "non-ASCII character".

---

Your code uses `[:*ascii*:]` in a regex character class, but that makes no sense ("`POSIX class [:*ascii*:] unknown in regex`"). If you want to negate the `[:ascii:]` POSIX class, you can use `[^:ascii]`, so

```
 s/[^[^:ascii:]]//g   # Strips everything except non-ASCII characters.
 s/[[:ascii:]]//g     # Same thing.
```

Is that what you are asking? If not, I don't see what the code you have posted has to do with the question you asked.